# web view is not playing MJPEG video file in ios6

Tags: iphone

I am working with uiwebView.

I given url to web view .

that url have some video into the format of "MJPEG".

```
NSMutableURLRequest * theRequest=(NSMutableURLRequest*)[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.test.org/cgi-bin/guest/Video.cgi?media=MJPEG"]]
[self.webView loadRequest:theRequest];
```

It's working fine in ios5,but it's not working in ios6.

Comment: I have been facing this problem for one week.Plz help me

Comment: Me too, must be a regression after rendering in webkit moved to a background thread in iOS6. File a bug with Apple, that's what I did.

Comment: Using MJPEG client we can play on imageview with socket communication.

Answer (score 1):

Try MotionJpegImageView instead of a UIWebView:

Article: http://thinkflood.com/support/redeye/software/open-source-software/motion-jpeg-image-view-ios/

Code: https://github.com/mateagar/Motion-JPEG-Image-View-for-iOS

Comment: thanks for given useful solution, My requirement is to show the MJPeg video stream in web view.Is there any solution ?

Comment: No. It looks like you will have to wait for Apple to fix it. I have successfully replaced a UIWebview with a MotionJpegImageView in my latest project.

Answer (score 0):

Using MJPEGClient it possible to play MJPEG video with socket. I have implemented referring following sample 
[MJPEG](https://github.com/horsson/mjpeg-iphone) 
Will be helpful for someone.